# How to use flash message in keystone.js?

Tags: node.js, message, keystonejs

I am use this code to display **flash message**

```
req.flash('success', 'Data saved...!!!');
```

When flash message is shown it looks like its part of content of website. So, is there any other way to show a message in `keystone.js`.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need some CSS to make it fixed in the center of the screen above everything else:

```
#flash-messages {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999999;
  text-align: center;
}

.alert{
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  color: #fff;

  h4 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}
.alert-warning {
  background-color: #d80000;
  border-color: #9c0000;
}
.alert-success {
  background-color: #2c9800;
  border-color: #247d00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For FlashMessage it looks like part of the website**
you imported/included the FlashMessage Mixin/Component in your view by the generator, otherwise, it won't show up.

**For how to use FlashMessage**
1. inclouds the FlashMessage Mixin in view, to where you want.
2. trigger FlashMessage API in controller `./routes/views/*.js` when condition match.

```
- `true` send all error messages to `req.flash`  
- `"validation"` only send validation error messages to `req.flash`\
- `"update"` only send update errors to `req.flash`
```

3.the message data will available in `res.locals.messages` for View to use.